# In Python, what is the difference between writable and mutable

Tags: python, oop, object

the document says about `__dict__`:

`object.__dict__`

A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.

So my question is, how to determine if an object is a writable object, and what are the differences between writable and mutable.

Here is the code

```
num = 1
num.__dict__
AttributeError: int object has no attribute __dict__

class MyClass(object):
    pass
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.__dict__
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object whose state can change is mutable.  Writing to attributes changes state.  So any object that has "writable" attributes is by definition mutable.

But there can be objects whose attributes you cannot change that are still mutable.  For example take `threading.Lock`.  You can `acquire` and `release` a `Lock`. These methods change the state of the `Lock`, but you cannot write to its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no general way to determine if an object is writable.

Not every object has a `__dict__` member that is writable.

Some classes use `__slots__`; this limits the fields and properties of the object to those defined in the list.

Other classes override **getattribute** and **setattribute** in such a way as to prevent users from accessing those classes; this is far easier to do in C language extensions in CPython.

Overall, the easiest way to tell if class is writable is to get an instance of it and call `setattr(obj, "xfoo", 1)` in a try-catch block.