# What does Python mean by a writeable attribute?

Tags: python

I was reading the Python documentation and came across the following line in relation to the [`__dict__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__):

> `object.__dict__`
>
> A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (**writable**) attributes.

What is a writable attribute?  What is the difference between a writable attribute and other types of attributes in Python?

Comment: [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659572/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-writable-and-mutable) may be helpful.

Comment: @DYZ So an object with an attribute that is writable can be directly changed by the user or some other entity. An attribute that is not writable cannot be directly changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

    @property
    def read_only_val(self):
        return self.value

my_obj = MyObject([10])
```

Writable attributes are those that can be set, e.g. using `setattr` or `=`

```
my_obj.value = [20]
setattr(my_obj, 'value', [20])
```

The values of these objects can be mutable or immutable, which will decide whether they can be modified in-place or not. *"Writable"* in the context of object attributes has nothing to do with mutability.

Non-writable attributes cannot be set. In our example, we defined `read_only_val` as a read-only property, which means we can't set it. Both these statements throw an `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

```
my_obj.read_only_val = [30]
setattr(my_obj, 'read_only_val', [30])
```

To further emphasize that *"writable"* in the context of object attributes has nothing to do with mutability, we can show that there is no problem in mutating the (non-writable) `read_only_val` attribute:

```
my_obj.read_only_val.append(40)
print(my_obj.read_only_val) # [20, 40]
```

Of course, if an attribute had an *immutable* value, we wouldn't be able to mutate it, and we would have to *set* the attribute<sup>provided it's writable</sup> to give it another value.

When we inspect `my_obj.__dict__`, we see it contains only the writable attribute:

```
print(my_obj.__dict__)
# {'value': [20, 40]}
```